# in sum, use case to compare incoming value with another column (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

ie:

```
| id | num |
| a  | 1   |
| b  | 2   |
| c  | 3   |
| d  | 4   |
| e  | 5   |
```

and this query is essentially what I'm trying to do:

```
select num as number, sum(case num > number then num else 0 end) as summation from table;
```

(I'm trying to sum up all the ints larger than the currently selected num in the column num.)

example output from above table:

```
| num | summation |
| 1   | 14        |
| 2   | 12        |
| 3   | 9         |
| 4   | 5         |
|5    | 0         |
```

The problem lies in the fact that I can't use the alias defined in the same select statement; is there another way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on MySQL 8.0 you can use window functions.

```
SELECT num,
       sum(num) OVER (ORDER BY num DESC) - num summation
       FROM elbat
       ORDER BY num;
```

Prior to MySQL 8.0 you can use a correlated subquery.

```
SELECT t1.num,
       coalesce((SELECT sum(t2.num)
                        FROM elbat t2
                        WHERE t2.num > t1.num),
                0) summation
       FROM elbat t1
       ORDER BY t1.num;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this using a correlated subquery:

```
select num,
       (select sum(num)
        from t 2
        where t2.num >= t.num
       ) - num as summation
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *correlated* subquery :

```
select num,
       (select sum(num)
        from table t2
        where t2.num > t.num
       ) as summation 
from table t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

this works, although a bit messy:

```
select num, (select sum(case when table.num > temp.num then num else 0 end)
  from (select * from table) as temp
) as summation
from table;
```

Comment: The parenthesis in your query aren't balanced.